# Is there any power of $4$ with natural exponent that can be represented as sum of several different powers of $5$ with whole non-negative exponent?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, exponentiation

There is a power of $2$ with a natural exponent, which can be represented as several different powers of $3$ with whole non-negative exponent. For example, $2^{2}=3^{1}+3^{0}$ or $2^{8}=3^{5}+3^{2}+3^{1}+3^{0}$.

There is also a power of $3$ with a natural exponent, which can be represented as several different powers of $4$ with whole non-negative exponent. For example, $3^{4}=4^{3}+4^{2}+4^{0}$.

However, is there any power of $4$ with natural exponent that can be represented as sum of several different powers of $5$ with whole non-negative exponent?

Comment: Doesn't seem likely.  You are asking for $n$ such that $4^n$ uses only $0's$ and $1's$ when written in base $5$.  Easy to see that $n$ must be even and easy to rule out small $n$. Once $n$ is big, it appears that all the digits are required.  I looked at convergents to $\frac {\ln 5}{\ln 4}$ to seek powers of $4$ that are relatively near powers of $5$, but got nowhere.  For instance, $4^{238}$ in base $5$ begins with $1000\cdots$ but it's $206$ digits long and all five possible base $5$ digits are used many times each.

Comment: Any power of $4$ will have either $4$ or $6$ as its last digit. Any sum of different powers of $5$ (including $5^0$) will have $0,1,5,6$ as its last digit. Hence you know that the sum of powers of $5$ must include $5^0$ and an odd number of other powers of $5$, and the power of $4$ must be even. So the question becomes "Is there any power of $16$ that can be represented as the sum of an even number of different powers of $5$, one of which is $5^0$?